# Windows Forms Authentication for WinForms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, .net-4.5, roles

I'm creating a Windows Forms Application with C# and .NET Framework 4.5 on my Visual Studio 2012.

I'm wanting now to create a Login Form, where the user can put some username and password (created in a database before) and the application validates and login the user. And if possible, with a "Roles Control".

I try to search on the Google, but i don't found this content related with Windows Forms, just on ASP.NET.

Does .NET Framework have any good (and official) solution to solve authentication issues in WinForms?

Answer (score 3):

No.  The Membership system is part of Asp.net, and while you might be able to use it in a winforms application, it wouldn't be very clean.

If you already have the username and passwords in the database, then your best bet is to just implement at straight forward authentication system, unless you are worried about people reverse engineering the code... In that case, it's a far more advanced thing to make it secure against reverse engineering.

EDIT:

Microsoft does have the [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx), but it's really a more complex system than you probably want.

Comment: I understand. I have the users database created. I will just create an validation of these data and show the dashboard form if the user exists and the password is correct. What do you think?

Thanks for the reply, by the way. And sorry for my freak english. :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a new form something like this.

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    public bool letsGO = false;

    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textUser.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return textUser.Text;
        }
    }

    private static DataTable LookupUser(string Username)
    {
        const string connStr = "Server=(local);" +
                            "Database=LabelPrinter;" +
                            "trusted_connection= true;" +
                            "integrated security= true;" +
                            "Connect Timeout=1000;";

        //"Data Source=apex2006sql;Initial Catalog=Leather;Integrated Security=True;";

        const string query = "Select password From dbo.UserTable (NOLOCK) Where UserName = @UserName";
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Username;
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    result.Load(dr);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void HoldButton()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textUser.Text))
        {
            //Focus box before showing a message
            textUser.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show("Enter your username", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            //Focus again afterwards, sometimes people double click message boxes and select another control accidentally
            textUser.Focus();
            textPass.Clear();
            return;
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textPass.Text))
        {
            textPass.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show("Enter your password", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            textPass.Focus();
            return;

        }
        //OK they enter a user and pass, lets see if they can authenticate
        using (DataTable dt = LookupUser(textUser.Text))
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                textUser.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username.", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textUser.Focus();
                textUser.Clear();
                textPass.Clear();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string dbPassword = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Password"]);
                string appPassword = Convert.ToString(textPass.Text); //we store the password as encrypted in the DB

                Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(dbPassword, appPassword));

                if (string.Compare(dbPassword, appPassword) == 0)
                {
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    //You may want to use the same error message so they can't tell which field they got wrong
                    textPass.Focus();
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    textPass.Focus();
                    textPass.Clear();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void textPass_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            HoldButton();
        }
    }

    private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HoldButton();
    }

    private void textPass_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            HoldButton();
        }
    }
}
```

then in your mainform do this:

```
public Form1(string userName)
{
    //this is incase a user has a particular setting in your form
    //so pass name into contructer
}
```

then lastly:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        LoginForm fLogin = new LoginForm();

        if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1(fLogin.UserName));

        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        //Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Hopefully this gives a general idea on what to do, though I'm sure theirs a much better way to do this, also note this isn't really secure front end.

Hope this helps:

EDIT: oh and before I forget dont use the

```
Select password From dbo.UserTable (NOLOCK) Where UserName = @UserName
```

I would just throw it into a stored procedure.  But anyway this isnt the best way to authenticate but its a working solution atleast get you going I hope