# User authorization for C# Winform applications (not ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, authorization

I would like to restrict certain features in a C# Winform application to specific users / user groups. I can see lots of examples using ASP.NET but very little information about how to do it for C# WInform applications. Any recommendations?

Comment: If the answer can solve you problem, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. If not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your idea is to limit the features you could try to do this: combine using the `.enable/.isEnabled` function that every obj in a winform has to make it usable or clickable by the user, with the `.visibility` command to change the interface in base of the type of user priviledge.

```
public class User()
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }

    public User() { }
}
```

Then when the user fill the form and press "login" for example you do something like:

```
User activeUser = new User();

activeUser.Username = nameTextbox.Text //ecc ecc for the psw

If(activeuser.IsAdministrator)
{
    buttonexample.Enabled = true;
    buttonexample.visible = true;

    otherbutton.Enabled = false;
    otherbutton.visible = false;

    // insert other commands for interface control
}
```

Other that this try to move around using different forms for different tasks, this will help break up the code to make it easier to work with.
A plausible structure could be:

- Login page (connected to a list where you have the user privileges defined for every user)
- Main interface where you hide & show only the features you want
- Maybe some others forms for user creation/change password/ecc

If you're instead asking for an actual authorization helping library or something else maybe rephrase the question a bit.

Comment: Many thanks sMuLe. This looks like your suggestion could be a good work around. Do you know if there are any off-the-shelf authorization libraries for C# WinForms? ASP.NET seems to have pretty good authorization features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: About that specifically I don't have an answer, check if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/bb384297(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) can help, or try checking other question with a similar purpose like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052944/windows-forms-authentication-for-winforms-application

Comment: Thanks sMuLe. Your response, along with my own research, has satisfied me that there isn't a good off-the-shelf solution for C# WinForms. Your proposed approach is a good workaround. Thank you.